# PHP file not writable in 777 directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I am running a website with the CodeIgniter framework and I have multiple pages from which users can upload files (profile pictures etc.).

This used to work fine until I recently deleted and replaced the uploads folder on the server. I set the permissions to 777 using FileZilla and confirmed the permissions were actually set afterwards. Still I got the CI error *The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.*

This error comes from the following function in system/core/Common.php (part of the CI framework) at the indicated line:

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_really_writable'))
{
    function is_really_writable($file)
    {
        // If we're on a Unix server with safe_mode off we call is_writable
        if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/' AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == FALSE)
        {
            return is_writable($file);
        }

        // For windows servers and safe_mode "on" installations we'll actually
        // write a file then read it.  Bah...
        if (is_dir($file))
        {
            $file = rtrim($file, '/').'/'.md5(mt_rand(1,100).mt_rand(1,100));

            if (($fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE)) === FALSE)
            {
                return FALSE; // RETURNS FALSE HERE <---
            }

            fclose($fp);
            @chmod($file, DIR_WRITE_MODE);
            @unlink($file);
            return TRUE;
        }
        elseif ( ! is_file($file) OR ($fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        fclose($fp);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what causes this. The folder path and permissions are exactly the same as before (in fact the permissions used to be stricter) and I haven't changed the script for my upload form. Everything works perfectly fine when I test it locally using Wamp.

Comment: Just for kicks, try `fopen($file, 'w+')` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: @Machavity This gives me the exact same result. Additionally, if I just make the function return true, I get the error *A problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked owner and group of *uploads* directory? If you are runing your server under Apache change group to your apache group (usually *www-data* or *http*) using *chown* command.

Comment: Could you give me the exact command for this? I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: chown -R username:groupname uploads

Comment: Looks like I don't have the rights to do this on the server (I'm using my student webspace from my university). It says `changing ownership of 'folder': Operation not permitted`